# Visibility and lifecycle of an anonymous function

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I try to filterout removed items:

```
  defp react_to_event({:delete, item}, socket) do
    id = item.id

    filter_by_id = fn list ->
      Enum.filter(list, fn
        {:id, ^id} -> false
        _ -> true
      end)
    end

    {
      :noreply,
      socket
      |> update(:new_items, &filter_by_id/1)
      |> update(:items, &filter_by_id/1)
    }
  end
```

But it seems like a lifecycle or scoping is off here: i get unused variable `filter_by_id` and undefined function `filter_by_id` errors here. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `filter_by_id = &Enum.reject(&match?({:id, ^id}, &1)`.

Comment: nice try, but `nested captures via & are not allowed` thanks for a `match?` hint tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&filter_by_id/1` will look for a named `filter_by_id/1` function in your module (or imported modules), not the anonymous function contained in the `filter_by_id` variable.

The following should work:

```
{
  :noreply,
  socket
  |> update(:new_items, filter_by_id)
  |> update(:items, filter_by_id)
}
```

`&` is used to captured named functions as variables and pass them as function arguments, but anonymous functions do not need to be captured because they can already be assigned in the first place.